# simplifying binding anonymous javascript functions to class

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I have a rather large set of javascript functions that I am working on refactoring into a set of classes using Prototype.

I was wondering if there was a way I could make binding anonymous functions to the class simpler? I keep forgetting to add the bind this at the end. Or is this just the way it is done all the time?

```
 var arr = this.getSomeArray();
 arr.each(function(t) {
     t.update(val);
     this.updateJSValue(t);
 }.bind(this));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your options are basically to call some function (`bind`, [`addMethods`](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/class#method-addmethods) or another function you write) or use a local variable rather than `this`:

```
var self=this;
arr.each(function(t) {
     t.update(val);
     self.updateJSValue(t);
});
```

If you've a large number of functions, the local variable requires the least typing For just a few functions, there isn't too much difference.

```
function ThingMixin(self) {
    self.foo = function(arr) {
        arr.each(function(t) {
             t.update(val);
             self.updateJSValue(t);
        });
    };
    ...
};
...
ThingMixin(Ralph.prototype);

// or an anonymous function:
(function (self){
    self.foo = function(arr) {
        arr.each(function(t) {
             t.update(val);
             self.updateJSValue(t);
        });
    };
    ...
})(Ralph.prototype);
```

Comment: is there any kind of performance increase/decrease with using the local variable? Most of the places where these are happening are in double for loops.

Comment: I'd expect memory usage to increase slightly, as the variables will live longer due to closures, but impact on performance should be negligible. Note that `bind` most likely makes use of a local variable.

Comment: This comment has more to do with correctness than performance, but if you want to bind to the same object for each iteration, set `self` outside the loop and the performance impact would be unnoticeable; if you want to bind to a different object, declare `self` inside the loop block.